# Implementing custom STL-like data structures

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, conventions

I have already implemented and tested the data structure and would now like to make it compatible with the collection of STL algorithms. Guidelines for implementing a custom iterator and the like. Specifically:

- What is the minimum set of operations that must be supported? (e.g. `++`, `+=`, `==`, `!=`?)
- Are there any properties of these operations that algorithms expect?

Ideally, these answers would be part of a bigger reference for implementing a STL-compatible data structure, but I'm not sure that such a document exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consult [the SGI STL documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/).  It has detailed requirements for each of the STL components, including [containers](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Container.html) and [iterators](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Iterators.html).

Effectively, for iterators, there are various types--input iterators, output iterators, forward iterators, bidirectional iterators, and random-access iterators.  The specification for each algorithm indicates the type of iterator required.

Comment: Indeed, the categorization on the SGI STL site is really worth referring to. Another option being (when creating a drop-in replacement) to simply provide the same interface as the container being replaced.

Comment: Unfortunately, the linked documentation is no longer available. Is there any other such source?